# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'NAP.DataSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, dataset

I need help.
I'm trying to import excel file to my sql database through c#. However, it shows the following error when putting the exceldatareader object to the dataset.

When I first tried it with my dummy project, it works fine. But when I transferred it to my main project, this happened.

Thanks in advance. Your help would be greatly appreciated

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgCRF.png)

```
 OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(open.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        IExcelDataReader excel = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        var result = new DataSet();
        result = excel.AsDataSet();

        foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                PoliceInfo c = new PoliceInfo()
                {
                };
                db.PoliceInfos.InsertOnSubmit(c);
            }
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What is `NAP.DataSet`? The compiler *says* there is an explicit conversion available: have you tried using it?

Comment: NAP is the name of my project. I don't know the correct syntax for the conversion. I've tried searching the web but I cannot find any solutions.

Comment: Did you define a `DataSet` class in your project? If so is there a method to create one from a `System.Data.DataSet`?